# How to disable queryset cache in Django forms?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django form that is supposed to filter choices using a queryset:

```
class GenerateStudentAttendanceForm(forms.Form):
    selected_class = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Class.on_site.filter(
        is_active=True,
        academic_year__is_active=True
    ))
    date = forms.DateField(initial=now().date())
```

The problem is that `Class.on_site.filter` is evaluated when the form is instantiated and is used for subsequent requests even if the site has changed.

How can I come around this?

Comment: Are you saying that even if one of the Class objects are deleted, it is still  available in the drop down ?

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal  I didn't tried that but it seems so, since the classes that are showing are from the default site.

Comment: You need to show what `on_site` is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I use django cintrib sites to serve the app accross multiple domains. on_site will return only classes of the current site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate the field by overriding the constructor of the `Form` class such that the queryset is evaluated on each instantiation of the form.

```
class GenerateStudentAttendanceForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(initial=now().date())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GenerateStudentAttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # add the key `selected_class` to the dictionary of `fields`
        self.fields['selected_class'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Class.on_site.filter(
            is_active=True,
            academic_year__is_active=True
        ))
```

Comment: It seems like you need to call `super(GenerateStudentAttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` first otherwise you get `'GenerateStudentAttendanceForm' object has no attribute 'fields'`.

Comment: Right. I implemented that way only in my project.

Comment: I am also given to understand, from other posts here at SO, that the `update()` method is a reliable way to force the queryset cache to be cleared.  You might be able to employ this somehow in the manner suggested by this answer.